# std::filesystem::path obtain relative path given a base path without temporary std::string conversion?

Tags: c++

I am trying to find the relative path of something not from root but from a given path instead, like find the difference of 2 paths using `std::filesystem::path` objects, for example:

```
std::filesystem::path path = "/var/log", file = "/var/log/folder1/folder2/log.log";
```

I was expecting that `operator-` was implemented for this kind of things so I was expecting something like:

```
std::filesystem::path rel = file - path; //With a expected result of "folder1/folder2/log.log"
```

EDIT: After some research and attempts, I finally managed to use `std::mismatch` like this:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::filesystem::path path, file;
    path = "/var/log";
    file = "/var/log/folder1/folder2/log.log";

    // Temporary string conversion
    std::string path_str = path.string(), file_str = file.string();

    std::filesystem::path str = std::string(std::mismatch(file_str.begin(), file_str.end(), path_str.begin()).first, file_str.end());

    std::cout << "Relative path is " << str.relative_path() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It will output: `Relative path is "folder1/folder2/log.log"`

My question is: Can the same be done without that temporary `std::string` conversion?

Comment: "Elegant" is mostly a subjective term. Can you reframe your question into objective terms?

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've updated question to clarify that fact

Comment: if `path` is always the start of the `file`, you can simply using `string.substr` and pass the length of path + 1 as the starting index.

Comment: `std::filesystem::relative` accepts a base path, so `std::filesystem::relative(file, path)`

Comment: @StormByte I think you should check Mile's comment. That's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`std::filesystem::relative` has an overload that accepts a base path and returns the first argument relative to the second, so all you need is:

```
auto relative_path = std::filesystem::relative(file, path);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a69d4055ccdd4809)

Comment: This answer deserves accepted than mine.

Comment: Oops, now I feel embarased that I overcomplicated it too much as I did not see that static function. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: I ended up going with the string solution since std::filesystem::relative requires std::filesystem::weakly_canonical to handle symlinks which has issues on windows rclone mounts. hope this helps someone with the same issue

Answer (score 1):

`std::mismatch()` can help you finding common paths. I assumed there's always a shared path. Starting from the mismatched path element, you can append the rest paths.

Following code printed `folde1/folder2/log.log` in vs2022.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main() {
  try {
    fs::path path = "/var/log";
    fs::path file = "/var/log/folder1/folder2/log.log";

    auto common = std::mismatch(path.begin(), path.end(), file.begin());

    fs::path relative_path;
    for (auto& iter = common.second; iter != file.end(); ++iter) {
      relative_path /= *iter;
    }

    std::cout << relative_path.string() << std::endl;
  } catch (const std::exception& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes, when I was researching I edited my question with my attempt using std::mismatch, yet you found a way without std::string temporary conversion which fits in the answer. Again, thanks!

Comment: I tried appending paths using standard algorithms like `std::copy` but failed. Maybe there's shorter way then using loops.

Comment: It's a pitty that some kind of "difference" is not implemented in fs like operator- or relative_to(path) which I think it would be interesting, specially if folders do not exist (yet)